# Word order in declarative statements

Tags: verbs, word-order

In these examples, why does the first sentence feel uncomfortable, compared to the second?

> 1. It's fascinating to use this camera to see how **will be** the back of my garden.
> 2. It's fascinating to use this camera to see how the back of my garden **will be**.

See here also

> 1. They want to see what the state **is** of their accounts.
> 2. They want to see what the state of their accounts **is**.

> 1. I need to know when **appeared** the baker.
> 2. I need to know when the baker **appeared**.

What's the rule here for the placement of the verbs? It seems not to be as logical as "following an S-V-O model".

Comment: Embedded questions resist inversion as per the _Penthouse Principle._ Accordingly, version 2 is to be preferred in sentences 1) and 3). Your second sentence doesn't seem to be asking the same thing.

Comment: @user405662 The question may not be new to ELU,  but the 'Penthouse Principle' has not been mentioned here before. Is a referenced answer a possibility? Or is that too tall an order?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I sure could try, but I know there are folks here with a sound command of the fundamentals germane to this question: I therefore am restricting my answer to a comment only.

Comment: Please do try, it would make a great answer @user405662